# Alertify alert confirm dialogs not working with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is [alertifyJS](http://alertifyjs.com/examples.html) and I need to implement this with rails.

I have downloaded this JS and CSS file and put into that `assets/javascripts/modules/alertify.js` `assets/stylsheets/modules/alertify.css`

`assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require modules/alertify
```

`assets/stylsheets/application.css`

```
 *= require modules/alertify
```

View

```
<%= link_to "Go!", new_employer_session_path, data: {confirm: "Are you sure? "} %>
```

But confirm dialogs not working.

What can I do now.

Thanks

Comment: What the error on network console?

Comment: Not showing any error

Comment: Ok then try the below solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Try the following if your `JS` and `CSS` working correctly

You need to declare method what method you need to action like below

I think this is a `GET` method then see this, you can change to anything that's your method

```
<%= link_to "Go!", new_employer_session_path, method: :get, data: {confirm: "Are you sure? "} %>
#=> declare a method :get, :post or :delete
```

Without declaring a method it's won't work

And add some `JS` code to your `JS` file `application.js`

```
$.rails.allowAction = function(element){
    if( undefined === element.attr('data-confirm') ){
        return true;
    }

    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(element);
    return false;
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(element){
    element.removeAttr('data-confirm');
    element.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(element){
    var msg = element.data('confirm');
    alertify.confirm(msg, function(e){
        if(e){
            $.rails.confirmed(element);
            return true;
        }
    })
};
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do, STEP BY STEP:

1) Add this to the gem file:

```
gem 'alertifyjs-rails'
```

2) Add this to /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require alertify
```

3) Add this to /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require alertify
 *= require alertify/default
 *= require alertify/bootstrap
```

4) Add this at the end of /app/assets/javascripts/application.js
It is necessary to make alertify work with the existing code.

```
$.rails.allowAction = function(element){
    if( undefined === element.attr('data-confirm') ){
        return true;
    }

    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(element);
    return false;
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(element){
    element.removeAttr('data-confirm');
    element.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(element){
    var company_name = "Your Company Name Security Confirmation";
    var msg = element.data('confirm');

    alertify.confirm(msg, function(e){
        if(e){
            $.rails.confirmed(element);
            return true;
        }
    }).set({title: company_name}).set('onfocus', function(){
        document.activeElement.blur();
    });

};
```

> The last set (.set('onfocus',...) makes possible to avoid the focus in
>   any of the buttons of the dialog. It looks prettier this way, but you
>   don't need to use it if you don't like it.

5) Go to the root of the project and run in the terminal:
bundle

6) Go to the terminal with the server running and stop the sever with: CTRL + C

7) Run the server again with:
rails server

8) Refresh the page in the web browser. It should work with your already existing code.

I hope this help!